# Generate a group ID with only one Window function

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to assign a group ID to my table.
For each group in "part" column, acording to order in "ord" column, the 1st elements I encounter in "id" column will receive a new_id 0, then each time I encounter a different ID, i increase the "new_id".

Currently, I need to use 2 window functions and the process is therefore quite slow.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
    (1,1,'X'),
    (1,2,'X'),
    (1,3,'X'),
    (1,4,'Y'),
    (1,5,'Y'),
    (1,6,'Y'),
    (1,7,'X'),
    (1,8,'X'),
    (2,1,'X'),
    (2,2,'X'),
    (2,3,'X'),
    (2,4,'Y'),
    (2,5,'Y'),
    (2,6,'Y'),
    (2,7,'X'),
    (2,8,'X'),
  ],
  ["part", "ord", "id"]
)

df.withColumn(
  "new_id", 
  F.lag(F.col("id")).over(Window.partitionBy("part").orderBy("ord"))!=F.col('id')
).withColumn(
  "new_id", 
  F.sum(
    F.col("new_id").cast('int')
  ).over(Window.partitionBy("part").orderBy("ord"))
).na.fill(0).show()

+----+---+---+------+
|part|ord| id|new_id|
+----+---+---+------+
|   2|  1|  X|     0|
|   2|  2|  X|     0|
|   2|  3|  X|     0|
|   2|  4|  Y|     1|
|   2|  5|  Y|     1|
|   2|  6|  Y|     1|
|   2|  7|  X|     2|
|   2|  8|  X|     2|
|   1|  1|  X|     0|
|   1|  2|  X|     0|
|   1|  3|  X|     0|
|   1|  4|  Y|     1|
|   1|  5|  Y|     1|
|   1|  6|  Y|     1|
|   1|  7|  X|     2|
|   1|  8|  X|     2|
+----+---+---+------+
```

Can I achieve the same using only one window function ?

Comment: I can think of a way by joining the dataframe to itself, but I am not sure if it's any faster than what you have now. You'd be exchanging one Window with a join.

Comment: Same execution plan, but you could do it all in one `withColumn` operation: `df.withColumn("new_id", F.coalesce(F.sum((F.lag(F.col("id")).over(w)!=F.col('id')).cast('int')).over(w), F.lit(0)))` where `w = Window.partitionBy("part").orderBy("ord")`. Using the `coalesce` over `na.fill(0)` will be slightly more efficient.